# Storybook + monorepo: display package versions within story

Tags: storybook

I'm migrating my old repo to a monorepo, and at the same time switching to Full Control Mode (and Storybook 6).

In my old repo, I could just do

`.storybook/webpack.config.js`

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(config.version),
    }),
  ],
```

then
`foo.stories.jsx`

```
/* global VERSION */
...
{VERSION}
```

to display the package version in the story.

In Storybook 6, I'm now doing:

`.storybook/main.js`

```
...
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          VERSION: JSON.stringify(config.version),
        }),
    );
...
```

but {VERSION} no longer prints out.

1. what am I doing wrong, and
2. how do I adjust this so it's {PACKAGE.VERSION} for each individual package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on my end. I needed to rename

const config = require('../package.json');
to
const packageConfig = require('../package.json');

then
VERSION: JSON.stringify(packageConfig.version),